# Ruby : Invocation does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-ruby, ruby-2.5

Im working with the aws sdk and want to use the [get_command_invocation method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v2/api/Aws/SSM/Client.html#get_command_invocation-instance_method). This is what I have in accordance with the docs:

```
resp = client.send_command(
    instance_ids: [instance_id],
    document_name: 'AWS-RunShellScript',
    max_concurrency: '1',
    max_errors: '1',
    timeout_seconds: 60,
    parameters:
        { commands:
              [command]
        }
)    

command_id = client.get_command_invocation(
        command_id: resp.command.command_id,
        instance_id: instance_id
    )
```

Using `puts` I know for sure that the method is receiving the command_id and the instance_id, both of which exist when i try and view them on the aws console. Yet I keep running into :

```
(Aws::SSM::Errors::InvocationDoesNotExist)
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.103.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.103.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/jsonvalue_converter.rb:22:in `call'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.103.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/idempotency_token.rb:19:in `call'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.103.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_converter.rb:26:in `call'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.103.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/response_paging.rb:12:in `call'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.103.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:24:in `call'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.103.0/lib/seahorse/client/request.rb:72:in `send_request'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/aws-sdk-ssm-1.84.0/lib/aws-sdk-ssm/client.rb:4534:in `get_command_invocation'
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I think invocation does not appear immediately. Have you tried to wait a bit before executing `get_command_invocation`?

Comment: @Marcin wow. yeah. never thought about that at all....do you mind making this as answer that I can accept ?

Comment: Thanks. Answer added :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by the fact that `invocation` is **not immediately available** after executing `send_command`.

The **solution** was to wait a bit before calling `get_command_invocation`. This could be achieved with a basic `while-type` loop which will keep pulling for availability of the invocation in a periodic manner, before continuing the normal program flow.